# Using phantom to import solana wallet that was created in cli

Tags: import, solana, spl, passphrase

I created a Solana wallet in Linus using CLI. The laptop I used got bad and I lost all the information therein. Now, I was able to get the passphrase for the wallet, but the problem is that, I can't use Phantom wallet to import my account.
What I have done:

1. I installed a Phantom wallet on a new device.
2. I selected "I already have a wallet".
3. I then pasted the Secret Recovery Phrase of the account...
   But instead of Phantom to display the account that owns the Passphrase, it was busy displaying other account I do not know, and when I scanned through them, I didn't see the account I wanted imported.
   Please what can I do as I didn't have the private key to the account?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct recovery phrase, you can then try **Add / Connect Wallet -> Create new Wallet**, it will add new keypair based on your mnemonic phrase. Eventually you should see your desired account (it might take several attempts depending on index where your desired account is located).